# Is there a Devise(Rails) like authentication plugin for Grails?

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-2.0

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise seems to be a well implemented and complete authentication solution. Is there anything that comes closest in Grails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Spring Security plugins come closest. There's a "core" plugin [spring-security-core](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-core) which manages authentication, password hashing, remember-me, etc. and several extension plugins that add functionality beyond the core. The [spring-security-ui](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-ui) plugin adds some of the workflow-based features like forgot password, user registration, etc.

Comment: Thanks Burt! It was that spring-security-ui that I was looking for.

Comment: Just to note, this will not work for Grails 3 (for now)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Burt. Also, there are better plugins/tools

1. [Nimble](http://grails.org/plugin/nimble) which is an extensive application base environment for Grails.
2. [Glance](https://github.com/glamdash/glamdash) - Grails Admin Dashboard Theme